# Get the value of each value in input tag using onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a loop of button and input tags

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($notifqry))
    {
        extract($row);
        if($type_of_notif == '1')
        {
        echo '<button class="dropdown-item"  onclick="notifview()">New Announcement!</button>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="notifid" name="notifid" value="'.$notifid.'">';

        }
    }
```

[image: the button/links]

and in my javascript

```
function notifview() {
var notifid = $('#notifid').val();
alert(notifid);
}
```

however, if I click the different button/links I only get the first row id only like this even i click the button w/ value of 3 or 4

[image]

Comment: In HTML `id` should be unique.

Comment: id should be unique in html, since you have duplicates, its going to choose the first one

Comment: how do I extract the value sir?

Answer (score 0):

`id`'s need to unique for every input field. Also, if multiple input fields are created dynamically you will need to use [`event delegation`](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to determine which button was clicked and then correspondingly extract that value.